# retrieve attributes from a nodes child node

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm experimenting with this xml:

```
<theFeed>
 <games>
    <game id="103"  period="" clock="">
        <team id="657" type="home" logo="1/12"  score="46"/>
        <team id="740" type="visitor"  seed="11" score="59"/>
    </game>
  </games>
</theFeed>
```

and I'm trying to get the attribute "score" from the first child of the game node, but when I use this code(javascript):

```
var Hlogo = theXml.getElementsByTagName('game')[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute('score');
```

it crashes. I can get attributes from the parent just fine using `getAttributes`...
is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Code please fix your formatting

Comment: sorry about that, also left out the main node <theFeed></theFeed>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var game = theXml.getElementsByTagName('game')[0];
var team = game.getElementsByTagName('team')[0];
var score = team.getAttribute('score');

console.log(game, team, score);
```

seems to work fine, providing `theXml` is valid (which i forced it to be `document`)

hope this helps -ck

Comment: that absolutely helped thanks. so xml won't read all of this on one line...how lame. now i see why JSON has gained so much popularity.

Comment: @codewombat if you mean chaining you could absolutely do: `var score = theXml.getElementsByTagName('game')[0].getElementsByTagName('team')[0].getAttribute('score');`  I just did it the way I did so it would be more readable... -ck

Comment: @codewombat, well you can but childNode[0] isn't always an "element", it may return an empty text node, so it's always safer to "find" what you want.. there is also the `.children` property that contains ONLY elements but it has inconsistent spotty coverage from browser to browser (old IE versions included comment nodes, and it didn't exist in FF < 3.5). So yeah `getElementsByTagName(..)` is the way to go.. -ck

Comment: @codewombat: That last comment is absolutely the key to the problem you were having.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add a reference to documentElement in your path:

```
var Hlogo = theXml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('game')[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute('score');
```